# I can't silence "TMOUT: readonly variable" message when I execute a command remotely

Tags: linux, shell, ssh

I am trying to execute a command remotely via use of ssh.
However due to TMOUT read only variable set on remote system , I get
 `"/etc/profile.d/tmout.sh: line 2: TMOUT: readonly variable"` as an out put along with the desired output of the command.
I tried silencing this via re directing stderr output to `/dev/null`, still it prints this message on console.

Tried many permutations combinations of redirection, not able to find the solution of this problem, any help would be appreciated?

```
ssh -q _HostName_ '. .bash_profile >  /dev/null 2>&1'
```

This should not print any message, however I am still getting :

```
"/etc/profile.d/tmout.sh: line 2: TMOUT: readonly variable"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you used grep -v afterwards. E.g:

```
ssh -q _HostName_ '. .bash_profile >  /dev/null 2>&1 | grep -v "MOUT: readonly variable"'
```